# mod_rewrite in .htaccess file for unknown first part of path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to write a rewrite rule to change path slugs to query parameters. It is for a web service, and should only rewrite this rule if the host starts with api. There are two slugs that I am trying to capture and rewrite. The first is optional and is a version (i.e. v1.2) and the second is the service domain (i.e. customers, transactions, etc.).

http://api.domain.com/v2.5/customers should rewrite to ?version=2.5&domain=customers

I also want to support a default version so that

http://api.domain.com/customers should rewrite to ?version=&domain=customers

Here is what my .htaccess file looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\..*
RewriteRule ^v([\d\.]*)?\/?([^\/]*)$ ?version=$1&domain=$2
```

The first example above works fine, but I can't get the default version path to work. I have tried a ton of different things. I thought starting with ^.*v would help, but it didn't. Anybody know how to make it match when you don't know the starting characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\..*
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !version=
RewriteRule ^(v([\d\.]*))?\/?([^\/]*)$ /?version=$2&domain=$3 [L]
```

This makes the `/v` part optional:

- `/v2.5/foo` -> `/?version=2.5&domain=foo`
- `/foo` -> `/?version=&domain=foo`
- `/v/foo` -> `/?version=&domain=foo`

Comment: @ChristopherMartin forgot that it's going to loop on you, add `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !version=` right before the rule (to go along with the HTTP_HOST condition)

Comment: Thanks! That worked like a charm. I'm not really sure what's going on. I thought that putting the grouping around the entire first part and making it optional would work. Why does it give me a 500 server error? Would you mind explaining?

Comment: @ChristopherMartin The rewrite engine continues to loop through all the rules until the URI going into the engine is the same after the rules are applied. Without some way of stopping it (like checking to make sure `version=` isn't already there), it'll loop some number of times before apache gives up and returns a 500